# Why is the accordion not decollapsing?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am Using Yeoman the angular app generator and bootstrap with Bower.
Just started to use bootstrap 3 and I have defined an accordion, this is a part of it:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">1. What is HTML?</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css defined in my index.html:

```
 <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Looks like the toggle does not set the collapse class in the next div. Do I have the wrong version of bootstrap / do I need to add some extra functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure it out, have to change href into data-target:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
           data-target="#accordionOne">
          Collapsible Accordion 1
</a>
```

And now it is time for a bevvie.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this page on Bootstrap 3 "Getting Started" section.

For Bootstrap 3 there are dependencies on JQuery set to version 1.9.0 or higher

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

There you can find a link to their Bower file hosted on GitHub where is clearly written the minimum version of JQuery required by Bootstarp 3.0.2

and

`href="#collapseOne"` this is missing on line number 4

Comment: I have jQuery set in the index.html it is loaded through bower. Not sure which version it is though.

Comment: href="#collapseOne" this is missing on line number 4